# Hide/show the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I am trying to hide various div elements, but I want to make it dynamic so if I unselect then it shows back up in the browser. This is easy enough with show/hide, but my problem is that I need to show/hide some of the same fields. It works on the first selection, but then the second run it won't do anything because it thinks it should show it as per the '.show()' in the first run.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks
S.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nat').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'no_nat')
      {
        $("#field25").hide();
        $("#field26").hide();
      }
      else
            {
        $("#field25").show();
        $("#field26").show();
      }
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nat2').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'no_nat')
      {
        $("#field25").hide();
        $("#field26").hide();
      }
      else
            {
        $("#field25").show();
        $("#field26").show();
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML like this:

```
<div class="form-row">
   <label>
      <span>Test1</span>
      <select name="field1" id="nat">
         <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
         <option VALUE="no_nat">1</option>
         <option VALUE="nat">2</option>
      </select>
   </label>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
   <label>
      <span>Test2</span>
      <select name="field2" id="nat2">
         <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
         <option VALUE="no_nat">1</option>
         <option VALUE="nat">2</option>
      </select>
   </label>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id='field25'>
   <label>
   <span>Test3</span>
   <input name="field25" type="text">
   </input>
   </label>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id='field26'>
   <label>
   <span>Test4</span>
   <input name="field26" type="text">
   </input>
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide complete html also

Comment: Can you please tell, where is id 'nat' & 'nat2'; Actually, I don't get what you are trying to express

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define $(document).ready twice. Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nat').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'no_nat')
      {
        $("#field25").hide();
        $("#field26").hide();
      }
      else
            {
        $("#field25").show();
        $("#field26").show();
      }
    });

    $('#nat2').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'no_nat')
      {
        $("#field25").hide();
        $("#field26").hide();
      }
      else
            {
        $("#field25").show();
        $("#field26").show();
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r2m9s8gx/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(this).val() === 'no_nat'
```

or

```
$('#nat').val() === 'no_nat'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to have a single handler like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name="field1"], select[name="field2"]').on('change', function() {
    var state = $('select[name="field1"]').val() == 'no_nat' || $('select[name="field2"]').val() == 'no_nat';
    $("#field25, #field26").toggle(state);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
  <label>
    <span>Test1</span>
    <select name="field1">
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
      <option VALUE="no_nat">1</option>
      <option VALUE="nat">2</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <label>
    <span>Test2</span>
    <select name="field2" type="text">
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
      <option VALUE="no_nat">1</option>
      <option VALUE="nat">2</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id='field25'>
  <label>
    <span>Test3</span>
    <input name="field25" type="text" />
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-row" id='field26'>
  <label>
    <span>Test4</span>
    <input name="field26" type="text" />
  </label>
</div>
```